# Is there a method to parallel the following pytorch code?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, dataloader

I have the following pytorch code that define a new matrix operation on two matrix points and primitives

```
def operations(points, primitives):
    """
    points shape: (batch size, number_of_points, 3)
    primitives shape: (batch_size, number_of_primitives,7)
    """
    gradient = torch.zeros(batch_size,number_of_points,number_of_primitives)
    for i in range(batch_size):
        
        temp_points = points[i,:,:]
        
        temp_primitives= primitives[i,:,:]
        temp = torch.zeros(number_of_points,number_of_primitives)
        for k in range(number_of_points):
            for j in range(number_of_primitives):
                temp[k,j] = torch.norm(temp_points[k,:]*temp_primitives[j,:3]+temp_primitives[j,3:6])
        gradient[i,:,:] = temp
    return gradient
```

Is there any method to parallelize such code to speed up?Thanks!

The above serialized code is implemented by myself, which is utilized in a deep-learning work. Is there any method to parallelize it? I have the following try:

```
def sstp(points,primitives):
    batch_size,number_of_points,_ = points.shape
    _,_,number_of_primitives = primitives.shape
    gradient = torch.zeros(batch_size,number_of_points,number_of_primitives)
    
    def level3(i,k,j):
        print("level 3 {} {}".format(k,j))
        temp_points = points[i,:,:]
        temp_primitives = primitives[i,:,:].transpose(1,0)
        gradient_ijk = torch.norm(temp_points[k,:]*temp_primitives[j,:3]+temp_primitives[j,3:6])
        gradient[i,k,j] = torch.norm(temp_points[k,:]*temp_primitives[j,:3]+temp_primitives[j,3:6])
    def level2(i):
        global pool
        pool.map(level3,[(i,k,j) for k in range(number_of_points) for j in range(number_of_primitives)])
    #level 1
    global pool
    pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(100)
    pool.map(level2, range(batch_size))
    pool.close()
    return gradient
```

but it throw an error  `bus error`. Could you help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: It seems your serialized code consumes too much memory so the process is killed. I'm not sure paralellization (by which I assume you meant vectorization) is the answer here because it usually consumes more memory. You may want to isolate which operation/tensor has the largest memory and try to reduce that. A solution that usually works for me to reduce memory usage is to reduce the batch size (try setting `batch_size` to 1).

Comment: Is there any method to parallelize the code?

Comment: Just from a quick glance, I don't see why it can't be done.

Comment: Hi, Kmkurn, I update my try as above. Could you help me with how to fix such issue? Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to parallelize (i.e. vectorize by *getting rid of loops*) to ultimately *make the code run faster*, right? You don't require multiprocessing, do you?

Comment: multiprocessing is better. Thanks